# jmespath - find a key wherever it is

Tags: python-3.x, jmespath

I have a very large json and I don't want to access a key with a very long filter (ie: `a.b.c.d.e.f.g.key1`). In the path there are not only scalar objects but also list.

Is there a way to write a filter in order to find a key wherever it is?

```json
{ "a": { "b": { "c": { "d": { "e": { "f": {"g": { "key1": 3 }}}}}}}}
```

Comment: if you are only interested in the value of the key, just convert the json to a string and do a string search for the key, you know that the value is what comes after `:` and until a `,` or `}`

Comment: That's my current solution. But I often use jmespath and I was wondering if it was possible to implement a search using this framework